# How is an Interface used as a Class?

Tags: java, interface, resultset

maybe this is a very dumb question.

I am trying to learn connecting to a MySql database using Java and I have done it. My question is:

```
ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

This code works fine. Then using

```
rs.next();
```

I can get the information I want.

But ResultSet is an interface? How can it have methods?

I have this import on top of my file:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
```

Thank you.

Comment: `ResultSet` is an interface, and the class of `rs.next()` is an instance of `ResultSet` (i.e. it `implements` it).  If you print `rs.next().getClass()`, you'll see the class name of the implementing class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ResultSet` is an `interface` that is implemented by the return type of `statement.executeQuery()`. `ResultSet` simply says "for anyone to implement my type, they have to provide at least these operations/methods". If the return type of `statement.executeQuery()` wants to implement ResultSet, it is up to that class to provide an implementation of all the methods in the interface.

Due to `polymorphism`, you can use any class that [`implements`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558111/what-does-implements-do-on-a-class) ResultSet as a ResultSet object itself.

You can [read more about Polymorphism here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 3):

`ResultSet` is indeed an `interface` - it specifies a contract. The `Object` returned from `statement.executeQuery(sql);` must fulfil this contract.

So `statement.executeQuery(sql);` return some `Object` that `implements` the `ResultSet` `interface` and hence has to provide concrete implementations to all the methods defined in the contract.

A simple example

```
public static interface MyInterface {

    void doStuff();
}

public static class MyInterfaceImplementer implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Doing stuff");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final MyInterface mi = new MyInterfaceImplementer();
    mi.doStuff();
}
```

Output:

```
Doing stuff
```

So `MyInterface` provides a contract that an implementing object must have a `public void doStuff()` method. `MyInterfaceImplementor` says that if fulfils that contract by declaring that it `implements MyInterface`.

Hence I can assign my reference to `MyInterface` to a concrete implementer of that `interface` and the method actually called is the one in `MyInterfaceImplementer`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the main characteristics of Object Oriented Programming and it's called inheritance.

What that means is that any child class can be used in a place where a mother class is declared.

In your case, the method `statement.executeQuery(sql);` returns a `ResultSet`. In this case, statement is creating a child class which implements `ResultSet` and returning it. As a child class, all mother class methods are implemented and callable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more of Polymorphism?

Comment: @Tushar Both words are correct. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 2):

The interfaces in `java.sql` package are implemented by the database vendor when they wrote the JDBC driver for you.

The implementation classes are loaded when you load the JDBC driver.

This is how your code can change databases just by switching the JDBC driver JAR and changing the connection parameters.  (As long as you stick to straight JDBC and don't use any vendor-specific SQL.)

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces have methods, in a well designed system you use the methods declared by the interface.  Any class implementing an interface must define all the methods declared by the interface and provide an implementation for them.

So when you use a method on the interface ResultSet you are actually using the method declared on the implementation of that interface.