# Do I have implement methods and variables which are inherited by the interface I am implementing?

Tags: dart, interface

So I am making a custom exception class which implements the abstract class Exception. It seems like I can create the class as follows

```
class CustomException implements Exception{

}
```

without any errors which suggests that you only need to implement non-inherited properties and methods. However, I can't confirm this suspicion which is why I am hoping for an answer.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558111/what-does-implements-do-on-a-class/4558147) help? This is a Java answer but it is the same for Dart.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Thanks for the link, I looked through it and I couldn't find an exact answer to the question.

Comment: There is a comment on the accepted answer of that question that answers your question. I also posted an answer on your question myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is incorrect. When you "implement" a class it's *necessary* to implement all the methods of that interface before it can be accessed. I would take a look at the [dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-classes) and read about abstract classes and using `implements`.

Comment: @vecohah The dart:core `Exception` class doesn't have any methods for you to implement.

Comment: The Exception class does have methods such as toString().

Comment: @vecohah The `toString()` method is part of the `dart:core` `Object` class which already has a default implementation for it.

Comment: @vecohah Does that make sense?